# Syntax error, expecting "="

Tags: ruby, syntax

I'm trying to write a Rubyish solution to problem 6 in Project Euler, because I have the propensity to write C in other languages. However, this code:

```
sqrsum, sumsqr = 0, 0
(1..100).each { |x| sqrsum, sumsqr += x, x**2 }
p (sumsqr - (sqrsum ** 2))
```

kicks up these errors:

```
/Users/Andy/Documents/Programming/Ruby/ProjectEuler/P6.rb:2: syntax error, unexpected tOP_ASGN, expecting '='
(1..100).each { |x| sqrsum, sumsqr += x, x**2 }
                                     ^
/Users/Andy/Documents/Programming/Ruby/ProjectEuler/P6.rb:2: syntax error, unexpected tPOW, expecting '='
(1..100).each { |x| sqrsum, sumsqr += x, x**2 }
                                            ^
```

What am I doing wrong here? Am I only allowed to assign in that syntactic structure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to make multiple assignments, but you are not using the assignment operator `=`.
Compare `sqrsum, sumsqr = 0, 0` with `sqrsum, sumsqr += x, x**2`.

Probably you wanted to write `sqrsum, sumsqr = sqrsum+x, sumsqr+x**2`.

Comment: I'm sorry, I still don't understand why my version (the second code snippet in your answer) isn't valid.

Comment: = can do multiple assignments, += can not

Answer (score 2):

why not just do `{ |x| sqrsum += x; sumsqr += x**2}`

Comment: Because I didn't know I could! +1

Comment: yeah a semi-colon in ruby basically acts as a newline, allowing you to execute multiple commands on a single line

Answer (score 2):

you could also use `inject`

```
sqrsum, sumsqr = (1..100).inject(:+), (1..100).inject(0) { |result,x| result + x**2 }
p(sumsqr - sqrsum**2)
```

[edit: thanks to commenters for pointing out :+ shorthand]

Comment: I like this method, but your example does not work. Can you help me understand why?

Comment: Oh! I figured it out! It should be `|result, x|`, not the other way around. Hooray for the docs. :)

Comment: The sum can also be written as `(1..100).inject(&:+)`

Comment: @Wayne Conrad: `inject` also takes a simple symbol: `(1..100).inject(:+)`.

Comment: @Andrew my fault, edited above. @Jorg and @Wayne cool, didnt know about :+

Comment: @Andrew, `.inject(:+)` is equivalent to `.inject { |a, b| a + b }`.  How it works, I haven't a clue: It's some magic buried in the interpreter, or library, or both.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want that

sqrsum, sumsqr = sumsqr + x, x**2

Comment: Your answer is the closest. It turns out what I actually wanted was

`sqrsum, sumsqr = sumsqr+x, sqrsum+x**2`